# C# Linq check the previous record to the current record and update the amount if duplicate

Tags: c#, linq

How can I use Linq to check the previous Account Number to see if it matches the current account number and if it does make the amount = 0?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you please add some code and examples of input and desired output?

Comment: What is your class declaration?  We need more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of Account Numbers. You could use Enumerable.Range for comparing to the previous value

```
var accountNumbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 3 };

var result = Enumerable.Range(1, accountNumbers.Count - 1)
              .Select(i => accountNumbers[i] != accountNumbers[i - 1] ? accountNumbers[i] : 0)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't tried your solution...I ended up just doing a for loop and checking each value to see if it matched the last one.

Comment: @MarkSmith, glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to clarify what "make the amount = 0" means. LINQ sequences are implicitly immutable, hence it is not possible to modify the amount in-place, but we need to return a new sequence (if you do want to modify the amounts in-place I would recommend using an array and a normal loop).
The answer provided by @Max works in principle, but is not performant as lists (and many other collection types) have only slow access to random elements.

LINQ does not have convenient tools for the task out of the box. Using only in-built methods a solution could be:

```
IEnumerable<int> accountNumbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 3 };
IEnumerable<double> amounts = new List<double> { 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 };

var possiblyInvalidAccountNumbers = accountNumbers.Skip(1); // The first account has no predecessor
var possiblyInvalidAmounts = amounts.Skip(1);

var validatedAmounts =
    accountNumbers.Take(possiblyInvalidAccountNumbers.Count())
        .Zip(possiblyInvalidAccountNumbers, (prevAccNo, accNo) => new { prevAccNo, accNo })
        .Zip(possiblyInvalidAmounts, (numbers, amount) => numbers.prevAccNo != numbers.accNo ? amount : 0.0)
        .Prepend(amounts.First());
```

Obviously, this code is somewhat convoluted, so a possible way to improve the clarity could be to write your own extension methods (e.g. a `Zip3()` method that takes three inputs would come in handy).

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't tried your solution...I ended up just doing a for loop and checking each value to see if it matched the last one.